# Data fetch delay

Tags: node.js, database, delay

I work in react native, node js and postgresql database and when I pull data in this screen, the data is delayed

```
const TextScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { module_id, section_id, screen_id, brojac } = route.params; // Dobijamo IDs direktno iz parametara rute
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(1);
  const [showParagraphs, setShowParagraphs] = useState([true]);
  const [paragraphs, setParagraphs] = useState([{}])
  const [nextScreenId ,setNextScreenId] = useState(0)
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

  


  

  useEffect(() => {
    dataHandler.get(`module/getParagraphs/${module_id}/${section_id}/${screen_id}`).then(response => {
      setParagraphs(response.data)
     
    })  
    }, [showParagraphs]);
```

Some other things are being done that are visible on the screen due to the delay of this data

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What is your question? It is expected that the data is a little delayed because it is being fetched from a database. You can handle this delay by adding a loading component, e.g. in your jsx `{loading ? <LoadingComponent /> : <LoadedContent />` where you define `loading` as a state variable.